# Batch Renaming Folders With Date And Version

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I am trying to batch rename about a thousand folders into a particular format - ("date" "version" - "title"). For example "100311a-Project Name". I am able to use a renaming application (Better Rename 10) to create a file like "100311-Project Name", but I often have multiple projects made on a single day so I would like to add a version letter, where the version is the order of projects (chronologically) that were created on this particular day. How can I do this using Better Rename 10? Thanks people!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, consider adding the time as option to differentiate about different projects. I'm sure the projects were not made in the same minute? That is more easily done than versioning.

Comment: Thanks LPChip! But, I would ideally like to have a version letter to keep the title somewhat concise.

Comment: What have you tried so far? While we're not a script writing service, we are quite happy to help you out when you've started a script yourself and got stuck.

Comment: @music2myear, apologies for my newbie question, but are you referring to a script within the command line? I've been using some basic Regex expressions within Better Rename 10, but maybe this is better done in the command line/terminal? Thanks!

Comment: (1) What operating system are you using?  Unix users generally avoid the word “batch” (and, to a lesser extent, the word “folder”), but we don’t want to make assumptions. (2) You say what you want to rename the directories ***TO**,* but not what they are now (what you want to rename *FROM* ). That makes your question impossible to answer. (3) It would help if you linked to the website for Better Rename 10.  As it is, anybody who wants to help you, but isn’t already familiar with that tool, would need to do a search to find its documentation. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) And, yes, showing some examples of commands that you’ve used would be a good thing.   (5) Have you done a search for bulk-renaming techniques?   We’ve got hundreds of questions about them just on this site.

Comment: @ekog I don't see any significant edit which would lay a base for a reopen of the question.

Comment: What about using a version control system like git or svn instead of relying on renaming folders?